# Gaussian smoothing in Octave

Tags: gnuplot, octave, gaussian, smoothing

I have a large amount of spectral lines and I want to simulate the Gaussian broadened spectrum of these. The lines are a N×2 matrix with the first column being the x coordinate and y the intensity. So in the end I want to place a Gaussian bell curve at each position x with a scaling factor y and get the sum of all these as a M×2 matrix where M divided by the range is the resolution.

N is in the order of a 1e6, the data points are NOT equidistant in x and are somewhere in the range of 0:4000, y is always positive.

Since the input matrix is created in Octave, I would like to process it in Octave as well, but I have not found a suitable function yet (or I didn't understand how to use them correctly).

However, I am able to get the desired result in gnuplot by

```
plot "matrix.dat" smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.8
```

With the help of `set table` I could also export it to a file. Unfortunately this takes a big amount of time for a single plot already, and I have a big number of these matrices.

Does anyone know how to speed up this process in Octave?